# date is not showing in proper format in react js

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs

I saved dob in mysql database as varchar(100) , when I select date it saved in my database as eg. 1983-06-24

but issue is when I render users dob in frontend it showing date as 1993-02-10T06:00:00.000Z

I want to show only 1983-06-24 in this way dont know why it add time extra as it not saved in db as well.

Comment: What is the datatype you are using in the DB?

Comment: I just want to save it as text value

Comment: is your api returning the  text as `1983-06-24`?

Comment: You can use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: If you're using `mysql` package, add `dateStrings: true` in your connection code.

Comment: Do not store dates as varchar. Store it as a date format.

Answer (score 0):

you can check using module https://momentjs.com/docs/

```
    import Moment from 'moment';

    render(){
        Moment.locale('en');
        var dt = '2016-05-02T00:00:00';
        return( {Moment(dt).format('d MMM')} )
    }
```